# Visual Studio 2012 Installation gives error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, installation

I have problem with installing Visual Studio 2012 Premium(pro and ulti too). When the 'acquiring' bar goes to 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Denenv' i've got an error. I attach screenshot and installator log. I have Windows 8 PRO 64bit.

Here is the screenshot:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61787551/log01.png

And here is the log:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61787551/vs_log.txt

And: "Nie mozna odnalezc elementu" mean "Cant find element" (i'm from Poland).

Somebody know what to do?

thanks in advance
Paul

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User

Answer (score 0):

Just install the available windows updates , also check this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dd43342c-4892-41a1-aaca-a42bf451d81c/visual-studio-2012-premium-setup-failed-microsoft-visual-studio-2012-devenv-element-not-found)

Comment: @superpawelTV have you checked my solution ?